# glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 0 in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, ios8

I am making an app that utilizes rendering to a texture with OpenGL ES 2.0. I have tested my code in iOS 7.1 numerous times without error. After updating to iOS 8.0 I am getting a return of 0 on glCheckFramebufferStatus. After doing some research I have found that glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 0 when there is an error. Does anyone know why this is happening after updating to iOS 8.0? Here is my code:

```
// Generate renderBufferer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);

// Generate  a framebuffer object for texture handling
glGenFramebuffers(1, &textureFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, textureFrameBuffer);

// Generate texture and bind to frameBuffer
glGenTextures(1, &layers[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, layers[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,  backingWidth, backingHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, layers[0], 0);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete textureFrameBuffer objects %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    // returns "failed to make complete textureFrameBuffer objects 0"
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: If I remove the check status for the frame buffer, I receive the following error in the output: "CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0"

Comment: Looks like you're making these calls without having a current context. You need to create a context, and make it current, before you can make any OpenGL calls.